# TFS 2012 TF50309 View Project Level Information

Tags: windows-server-2008

I had create a testing collection name "Default Collection", at the "Default Collection" Group membership, I create "TFS Team" and put a user name window login "CLL" and set "Edit collection-level" information and "View Collection-level information" to true

[image]
when I access to the web, and click browse
[image]

I hit this error, I had try many way to control the security, the only way allow me to browse for different project but not able to change security is to add the "TFS Team" into Project Collection- Test Service Account, it is the correct way to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please go to Team-> Team Project Settings->Security and make sure your group has 'View project-level information' set to Allow.

Comment: Yes, it is set to allow, but why still can't browse? the only way I can browse the project is to add "TFS Team" into "[DefaultCollection] Collection test Service Account", is that the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you created Group "TFS Team" on Collection Level and set "**view collection-level information**". 
To browse to Projects, you will need "view **project**-level information" permission on each Team Project. Please follow the steps below to set this permission:

1. Open Team Explore **2010**
2. Connect to your TFS 2012 server.
3. Go to menu Team->Team Project Settings->Security
4. Add Group "TFS Team" and allow "view project-level information" permission.

FYI, Group "[Collection]\Project Collection Administrators", "[Collection]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts", "[Collection]\Project Collection Test Service Accounts" have been added to each Team Project **by default**. That's why you can browse the project after added "TFS Team" into "Test Service Accounts". You will **NOT** see these three groups from TFS 2012 Web Access. But you will see these groups with Team Explore 2010.